# how to convert Bitmap to Imagesource Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to convert `bitmap to Imagesource`. I have searched online but I can only find examples the other way around.

Do you please have any examples?

Comment: What platform are you using and how are you creating your bitmap object?  Generally you create an ImageSource using image data - either a file, a stream, or a url.

Comment: Try to convert the bitmap to stream first on the native platform, then convert the stream to imageSource. You could use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to achieve the function on Android and call the method in the shared project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to convert Bitmap to Imagesource Xamarin

You coudl convert the bitmap to stream first on the native platform, then get the imageSource from the stream. You could use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to achieve the function and call the method in the shared project.

Check the code:

Create an interface in the shared project.

```
public interface IGetFileStream
{
    MemoryStream getStream();
}
```

Implement the interface in the required platform projects.

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(DroidGetStreamImplement))]
namespace App19F_9.Droid
{
    public class DroidGetStreamImplement : IGetFileStream
    {
        public MemoryStream getStream()
        {
            var bitmap = ...;

            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
            bitmap.Recycle();
            return stream;
        }
    }
}
```

Resolve the platform implementations from shared code.

```
public partial class Page5 : ContentPage
{
    public  Page5()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var stream = DependencyService.Get<IGetFileStream>().getStream();
        image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(stream);
    }
}
```